# which are the numerical methods for Approximating this Integral and solve

Tags: integration

this is the integral that I would like you users work, I would like to know what methods and with all the steps as they arrive at the approach, I'm finishing a new numerical method to and I am doing some tests, to compare it with all methods made by all users of this forum, and see if still worth the way as I pose and solve the exercise, there are no limitations can use your computer with the wolfram alpha or matlab to corroborate the numerical solution , but if the essence of the exercise is to see what methods and apply formulas to arrive at this result, Integrate[Sin[(x^4)], {x, 3*Pi*E, 73*Pi*E}] where E is number euler approximately 2.718281828 where Pi is number aproximately 3.141592654, or integral, I write several times that language is not used here

$$\int_{3\pi e} ^{73\pi e} \sin(x^{4})dx$$

I hope your solutions .....

thanks

att
jefferson alexander vitola  :D

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!

For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

It would be polite to provide your own thoughts on your question.

Comment: hello TZakrevskiy,thank you very much for editing my question correctly, you're very kind.
any question I do, I do not speak English and use a translator online, I'm not clear if you ask me.
an oscillatory integral type that I resolved on my own numerical methods, when I asked wolfram alpha to solve numerically program was delayed 3 seconds, and when I asked to see where the approach had made the program gave an incredible response 22 000 pages, I always stay with  to see that alternative methods can be done to solve the same exercise,,

thanks

jefferson alexander vitola

Comment: @TZakrevskiy just so you know it's pretty annoying when people say read this, this, this and this without giving much explanation. Perhaps summarizing the key points you find important would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

WolframAlpha obtains its answer by first finding an *exact* result in terms of special functions and then using specialized techniques for that type of function to find a numerical approximation to that function.  You can see this in the the WolframAlpha's response:

[image]

In Mathematica, this is essentially equivalent to doing the following:

```
Chop[N[Integrate[Sin[x^4], {x, 3 Pi*E, 73 Pi*E}]]]
(* Out: 9.22383*10^(-6) *)
```

The `Chop` command removes a negligible imaginary 0.

Note that the answer of about $9.22 \times 10^{-6}$ is very close to zero, which is perhaps not too surprising when you look at the graph.

Due to the large interval of integration and highly oscillatory nature of the integrand, the integral is quite tricky to approximate using direct numerical techniques.  A direct call to Mathematica's `Integrate` command generates warning messages and the result is correct to only one significant digit.  There is a technique called [Levin integration](https://www.google.com/search?q=levin%20integration) that is specially designed for this type of integral.  This technique can be invoked from Mathematica to obtain a good numerical estimate as follows:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[x^4], {x,3Pi*E,73Pi*E}, Method->"LevinRule"]
(* Out: 9.22383*10^(-6) *)
```

As pointed out in the comments, Matlab can also obtain the exact solution via its symbolic toolbox:

```
syms x;
double(int(sin(x^4),x,3*sym(pi)*sym(exp(1)),73*sym(pi)*sym(exp(1))))

(* Out: 9.2238e-06 *)
```

While not built in, Levin integration is available via the [Chebfun project](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/).

Comment: Matlab's `sym/int` (`syms x; s = int(sin(x^4),x,3*sym(pi)*sym(exp(1)),73*sym(pi)*sym(exp(1)))`) returns the "exact solution" in terms of a pair of $_1F_2$ hypergeometric functions, which correctly evaluate (`double(s)`)to 9.22383e-06. Levin integration can be accomplished in Matlab via [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23972-chebfun/content/chebfun/examples/quad/LevinIntegrate.m) from the well-known Chebfun project.

Comment: @horchler  hello. thanks for trying to solve my exercise, I have three questions for you that you are an engineer  and expert in matlab you know any practical application or industrial application for this oscillatory integral? . I can I sell my formula or procedure matlab but keep my name?. As may be worth in money or what would be the price of this type of formula?

Comment: thank you very much for thoroughly analyzing this exercise, this forum is the best I've met in my life, I want to congratulate you in particular @Mark McClure  and others users who wanted to help  to see how many methods and which is the best of all, all observations that you make are totally true, thank you very much, and   all can work the exercise by  for more methods and procedures ...I will be attentive to your solutions. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\int_{3\pi e}^{73\pi e}\sin(x^{4})dx$

$=\int_{3\pi e}^{73\pi e}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(x^4)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int_{3\pi e}^{73\pi e}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{8n+4}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{8n+5}}{(2n+1)!(8n+5)}\right]_{3\pi e}^{73\pi e}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(73^{8n+5}-3^{8n+5})\pi^{8n+5}e^{8n+5}}{(2n+1)!(8n+5)}$

This is the exact result, for the approximate result, you can just take first few terms to sum up.

Comment: This is a very cool technique indeed! But it typically works well when used over small intervals about the center of the power series. Unfortunately, we have a large interval nowhere near the the center of the power series. So it doesn't work too well in this example.

Comment: Here's a more quantitative way to look at my previous comment. The error formula for alternating series states that the error from the $n^{th}$ partial sum is bounded by the absolute value of the $n^{th}$ term and this gives us one way to approximate how many terms are needed.  In the numerator, we have about $(73*\pi*e)^8$ raised to the $n$ and in the denominator (using Stirling's formula) we have about $(4n/e^2)$ raised to the $n$. If we set $(73*\pi*e)^8=(4n/e^2)$ and solve for $n$ we see that we need around $10^{22}$ terms to get the error less than $1$.

Comment: Numerically, this will probably be a disaster, as you will be subtracting very large values to get a small value.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^4$ gets rather large,
you are going to have a
violently oscillating function
if evaluated as written.

One possibility is to split the integral
into regions where
the function is of constant sign.
These will be when
$\sin(x^4) = 0$ or
$x^4 = \pi n$
or 
$x = \sqrt[4]{\pi n}$.
Then choose 3 or so points
for each of these intervals
(a Gauss rule would probably be OK)
to numerically estimate the interval.

Another, somewhat equivalent
way,
is to make the variable of integration
smoother.
If $x^4 = y$,
$4 x^3 dx = dy$
or
$dx = dy/(4 x^3)
= dy /(4 y^{3/4})
= dy\ y^{-3/4}/4
$
so
$\int \sin(x^4)dx
=\frac1{4}\int \sin(y)y^{-3/4}dy
$.

For your particular limits
$\int_{3\pi e}^{73\pi e} \sin(x^4)dx
=\frac1{4}\int_{(3\pi e)^4}^{(73\pi e)^4} \sin(y)y^{-3/4}dy
$.

Note that for large $y$,
the $y^{-3/4}$
will make the values small,
so that numerical bounds can be given
for values out towards the right.

For this type of integral,
I would recommend an adaptive integration scheme,
which would use more points
where the function is unruly,
rather that a scheme
such as Romberg
that uses all equally spaced points.

Comment: The substitution you suggest was one of the first things I tried, but the resulting integral was still not doable with elementary techniques.